# Assign private IP only with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to create an EC2 instance. What I am trying to achieve is only assign a private IP. No public IP. Everything gets created fine and it creates a DNS entry for the private IP, but it also creates a public IP. How can I tell it to not create a public IP. Here is my template. The vpc_id and subnet_id is on a private network.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation template for creating riskInternalElk instance with DNS record'
Parameters:
Resources:
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupName: "{{security_group_name}}"
      GroupDescription: "{{security_group_name}}"
      VpcId: "{{vpc_id}}"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
{% for item in security_group_ingress %}
      - IpProtocol: "{{item.protocol}}"
        FromPort: "{{item.from_port}}"
        ToPort: "{{item.to_port}}"
        CidrIp: "{{item.cidr_ip}}"
{% endfor %}
  NetworkInterface:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: "{{subnet_id}}"
      Description: "{{subnet_description}}"
      GroupSet:
      - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      SourceDestCheck: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Network
        Value: Web
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name"
        Value: "{{instance_name}}"
      ImageId: "{{image_id}}"
      InstanceType: "{{instance_type}}"
      KeyName: "{{key_name}}"
      NetworkInterfaces:
      - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref NetworkInterface
        DeviceIndex: 1
      BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: "{{device_name}}"
        Ebs:
          VolumeType: "gp2"
          VolumeSize: "{{volume_size}}"
          Encrypted: true
          DeleteOnTermination: false
  DnsRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: "{{hosted_zone_name}}"
      Comment: "DNS name for risk internal ec2 instance."
      Name: "{{host_name}}"
      Type: A
      TTL: '60'
      ResourceRecords:
      - !GetAtt EC2Instance.PrivateIp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the information in the EC2:Instance resource set for the [NetworkInterfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html) differently to have it deviate from the subnets setting for assigning a public IP.

Specifically set the **AssociatePublicIpAddress** to "False" and move your NetworkInterface resource to be in-line like this:

```
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name"
        Value: "{{instance_name}}"
      ImageId: "{{image_id}}"
      InstanceType: "{{instance_type}}"
      KeyName: "{{key_name}}"

      NetworkInterfaces:  
      - AssociatePublicIpAddress: false <--- This should do it
        DeleteOnTermination: false
        DeviceIndex: 0
        SubnetId: "{{subnet_id}}"
        Description: "{{subnet_description}}"
        GroupSet:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
        SourceDestCheck: true

      BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: "{{device_name}}"
        Ebs:
          VolumeType: "gp2"
          VolumeSize: "{{volume_size}}"
          Encrypted: true
          DeleteOnTermination: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Subnet for the setting, "Auto-assign public IPv4 address".

Change it by going to the VPC Console and selecting the Subnet-->Actions-->"Modify auto-assign IP settings".

Answer (score 0):

You control the assignment of public IP addresses to EC2 instances thru the subnet configuration. The subnet defines `MapPublicIpOnLaunch`. This also means that the subnet must be part of your cloudformation stack.

If you are using Auto Scaling, then you have the option `AssociatePublicIpAddress` in `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration`

[AWS::EC2::Subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html)

[AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html)